# Identify the first row and last row in a merged cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am applying some Conditional Formatting to an Excel sheet which involves some complex metrics, therefore have decided to pursue this method using VBA.

Because of the way the spreadsheet is laid out, the L1's and L0's are contained in merged cells.  I need a way to identify the first and last row in a group of merged cells, the code below does not work as I is in a constant looping state.  I need a way to look at the merged cell as it finds it, and then identify the first row and last row in that merged cell area. Current code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim I As Integer, J As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long, L0FirstMergedRow As Long, L0LastMergedRow As Long, L1FirstMergedRow As Long, L1LastMergedRow As Long
Dim Baseline As Long, Forecast As Long, Balance As Long, Actual As Long
Dim Baselinerng As Range, Forecastrng As Range, ActualRng As Range
Dim MaximumBaseline As Double, MaximumForecast As Double, MaximumActual As Double
Dim r As Long, actualvalue As Long

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

actualvalue = 0

For I = 3 To LastRow

    'Code looks for merged cells and marks the row numbers
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).MergeCells = True Then

        L1FirstMergedRow = I
        L1LastMergedRow = I + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).MergeArea.Cells.Count

    'Set ranges of Baseline, Forecast and Actual cells
        Set Baselinerng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Range(Cells(L1FirstMergedRow, 6), Cells(L1LastMergedRow, 6))
        Set Forecastrng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Range(Cells(L1FirstMergedRow, 7), Cells(L1LastMergedRow, 7))
        Set ActualRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Range(Cells(L1FirstMergedRow, 8), Cells(L1LastMergedRow, 8))

        MaximumBaseline = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Baselinerng)
        MaximumForecast = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Forecastrng)
        MaximumActual = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ActualRng)

    'Code looks for values in Actuals Column before it executes.
        For J = L1FirstMergedRow To L1LastMergedRow
                If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(J, 8).Value <> "" Then
                    actualvalue = actualvalue + 1
                End If
        Next J

    ' Colour Cells Blue based on calculation of Actual dates
        If actualvalue = L1LastMergedRow - L1FirstMergedRow + 1 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 255)
        End If

        If MaximumActual = 0 Then

            If MaximumBaseline <> 0 And MaximumForecast <> 0 Then
                Balance = MaximumForecast - MaximumBaseline
            Else
                GoTo NextLoop2:
            End If

            If MaximumBaseline <= MaximumForecast Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            End If

            If MaximumBaseline < MaximumForecast And Balance <= 5 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            End If

            If MaximumBaseline < MaximumForecast And Balance > 5 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Cells(I, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If

        Else
        GoTo NextLoop2:

        End If
    End If

NextLoop2:
Next I
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
Set MyMergedRange = Range("d20").MergeArea
FirstRow = MyMergedRange.Row
LastRow = MyMergedRange.Row + MyMergedRange.Rows.Count - 1
```